# The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, url-routing

I'm trying to access *sitename*/news/id/1, but it gives me this error. I've been trying to fix it for the past 30 mins and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The config:

```
            //...
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]/id/[/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'news' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/news/id[/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'news',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    //...
```

Comment: I have never used Zend routes before, but `[:controller` looks wrong. Are you sure it should not be `[:controller]`? Also, what does `id` in `[/:action]id` do in the route, all on its own? The route just looks *off* to me.

Comment: It's supposed to be /id/ and then the actual id

Answer (score 1):

Your `news` Route is of Type `literal`. But it Should be of Type `Segment`.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#http-route-types for the different Route types.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're expecting this to match your 'default' route. Since that route is a child route of your application route, `example.com/application/news/id/1` would match, but not `example.com/news/id/1`. I would get rid of the application route and just have the default route in its place.

Comment: I removed the id route from `application`, but it's still not working

Comment: In that case please could you add your updated route config  to your question, along with info about which route you're expecting to be matched by your `/news/id/1` URL.